# How to create a shortcut to a text file

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, file-system, file-management

I have a text file somewhere on the SD card.

How can I create a shortcut to this file on the "desktop" to open it immediately?

(HTC Wildfire)

Answer (score 1):

[Amaze file manager](https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager), offers this option as well, just long click on a file or folder you would like to be able to enter to with a shortcut from the home screen and tap the 3 dots menu button at the top, then choose `add shortcut`.

Amaze File Manager is a FOSS file manager and it has many nice features stock file managers don't offer. For example, you can open with it files as text/image/video/audio/database with the application of your choice no matter what the file extension is - that's very useful for users who create or download/sync text files with no file extension or non relevant file extension like `.log`, `.yaml`, `.json` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another app: [Shortcut Maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rk.android.app.shortcutmaker).
It works with the latest version of Android.

After installing the app, go to Widgets by long-tapping the home screen and click on shortcut maker. Then add the required file/folder.

Comment: You have posted five answers in toto. They are all recommending this particular app. What exactly is your affiliation with this app? Our site's policy requires full disclosure of affiliation with the product within every post the product is mentioned.

Comment: I have no affiliation with this product. The other solutions didn't work in the latest version of Android and I just got a little excited on finding the app.